# Play! Authenticate sample throwing exception

Tags: playframework

I tried running the sample application given in the Play! Authenticate framework, but it keeps throwing an exception.

```
/Users/Parjun/code-samples/play-samples/play-authenticate/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/controllers/Signup.java:182: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : method noCache(play.mvc.Http.Response)
[error] location: class com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate
[error]         com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate.noCache(response());
```

noCache is a public method defined in the Controller. Unable to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I uploaded a new binary snap to the repository for 0.2.1 - should be fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples master download from GIT have a dependency on the 0.2.1-SNAPSHOT which doesn't have the noCache method included. If you want to check out the samples, either comment out those lines in the code or download the 0.2.1 snapshot:
[here](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tags)